# the suggested way to use clEnqueueMapBuffer and clEnqueueUnmapMemObject when implementing zero copy

Tags: opencl

I am playing deep learning with opencl, the output size of the tensor is fixed.

In cuda, I can use zero copy via cudaMallocHost, this can be called in the initialization. And I can read the output of the tensor from the host without explicitly calling cudaMemcpy.

It's very efficient since it's called only one time over the entire execution of my program. I don't need to call cudaMallocHost every time after forwarding.

And when I try to implement zero copy in opencl, in some implementations they call clEnqueueMapBuffer and clEnqueueUnmapMemObject every time after forwarding when you want to read the output of the tensor.

Here is the example (https://github.com/alibaba/MNN/blob/master/source/backend/opencl/core/OpenCLBackend.cpp#L291).

But I find that the overhead of clEnqueueMapBuffer can not be neglected, sometimes the latency is quite large.

Is this really suggested way to do so? Can I call clEnqueueMapBuffer only one time in the lifetime of my program and call clEnqueueUnmapMemObject one time when the end of my program? is there any issue to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OpenCL implementation supports Shared Virtual Memory (introduced in 2.0), that feature allows you to do something similar, and much more.

For OpenCL 1.x, unless your OpenCL implementation makes any guarantees above and beyond the standard (which I'd expect it to do via an extension), you *must* unmap a buffer before a kernel gets write access to it, and likewise, you *must not* allow a kernel to read from it while it is mapped for writing.

This is explained in the [`clEnqueueMapBuffer` specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html):

> Reads and writes by a kernel executing on a device to a memory region(s) mapped for writing are undefined.
>
> The behavior of writes by a kernel executing on a device to a mapped region of a memory object is undefined.

In version 1.2, this was expanded, but the gist is the same:

> If a memory object is currently mapped for writing, the application must ensure that the memory
>   object is unmapped before any enqueued kernels or commands that read from or write to this
>   memory object or any of its associated memory objects (sub-buffer or 1D image buffer objects)
>   or its parent object (if the memory object is a sub-buffer or 1D image buffer object) begin
>   execution; otherwise the behavior is undefined.
>
> If a memory object is currently mapped for reading, the application must ensure that the memory
>   object is unmapped before any enqueued kernels or commands that write to this memory object
>   or any of its associated memory objects (sub-buffer or 1D image buffer objects) or its parent
>   object (if the memory object is a sub-buffer or 1D image buffer object) begin execution; 
>   otherwise the behavior is undefined.

If you find that map/unmap has a high overhead, you are probably not hitting a zero-copy code path in your OpenCL implementation, and the driver is actually copying the memory contents. If in doubt, check with your implementation vendor to see how they recommend you implement zero-copy buffers in OpenCL. Zero-copy buffers are not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: I create a gist (https://gist.github.com/twmht/8e514b9dc7b318b07faab387831ded81) to verify the undefined behavior, but everything  works without unmap operation. Do you know the reasons?

Comment: You can't "verify" undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour means you can't predict what will happen. This includes that it might appear to work "correctly" under some circumstances, but will subtly break in other situations. Also, a GPU driver update might change the behaviour, for example.